# Transpose/Pivot SQL Results for a column that varies

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I need to transpose data.

Here is my source data from the DB.

| P_PRODUCT | P_QUALIFIER | P_STRINGVALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8797514792961 | aws classification | E9018-B3 |
| 8797514792961 | diameter | 0.15625 in |
| 8797514792961 | trade name | American Filler Metals |
| 8797514792961 | weight | 10 lb |
| 8800491405313 | brand name | Carhartt® |
| 8800491405313 | closure | Zipper |
| 8800491405313 | clothing size | 46" X 32" |
| 8800491405313 | clothing type | Bib Pants, Overalls |
| 8800491405313 | color | Brown |
| 8800491405313 | length | 32 in |
| 8800491405313 | lining | Unlined |
| 8800491405313 | material | Cotton, Duck |
| 8800491405313 | material weight | 12 Ounce, Heavy Weight |
| 8800491405313 | seam | Triple-Stitched Seams |
| 8800491864065 | brand name | Carhartt® |
| 8800491864065 | closure | Zipper |
| 8800491864065 | clothing size | 46" X 36" |
| 8800491864065 | clothing type | Bib Pants, Overalls |
| 8800491864065 | color | Brown |
| 8800491864065 | length | 36 in |
| 8800491864065 | lining | Unlined |
| 8800491864065 | material | Cotton, Duck |
| 8800491864065 | material weight | 12 Ounce, Heavy Weight |
| 8800491864065 | seam | Triple-Stitched Seams |

I am trying to transpose/PIVOT my data so it looks like the following:

| P_PRODUCT | aws classification | diameter | trade name | weight | brand name | closure | clothing size | clothing type | color | length | lining | material | material weight | seam |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8797514792961 | E9018-B3 | 0.15625 in | American Filler Metals | 10 lb | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 8800491405313 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | Carhartt® | Zipper | 46" X 32" | Bib Pants, Overalls | Brown | 32 in | Unlined | Cotton, Duck | 12 Ounce, Heavy Weight | Triple-Stitched Seams |
| 8800491864065 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | Carhartt® | Zipper | 46" X 36" | Bib Pants, Overalls | Brown | 36 in | Unlined | Cotton, Duck | 12 Ounce, Heavy Weight | Triple-Stitched Seams |

I am struggling to figure out how to use the PIVOT function to accomplish this task. Also the data in my p_qualifier column tends to vary on what product I pull.

Comment: I have recently done this myself. You'll have to dynamically create the list of column headers from some other sub select and the create the pivot query using string concatenation and dynamic sql. Or at least, this is how I did it using sql server. Oracle / mysql may differ.

Comment: A quick google brings up this stack. Probably worth a read. The selected answer is quite similar to what I had to do. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64871021/use-pivot-for-dynamically-changing-column-headers-using-sql-in-oracle

Comment: Little soap box. If it has to be dynamic it has to be dynamic sql. But it's good to make sure you really want and need this to be dynamic. If it's for presentation, maybe that's best left to presentation layer. If it's going to get written elsewhere in the database, having dynamic stuff going on like that can be it's own can of worms. There's a reason the big dbms players don't support dynamic naming, even though something like pandas does.